# Replacing a loop query

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-server-2005

I have the following tables set up:

```
   CREATE TABLE app_detail
(
CustID1 int,
CustID2 int,
AppDate datetime
)

CREATE TABLE inv_detail
(
CustID1 int,
CustID2 int,
PostDate datetime,
ClearDate datetime,
Amt float
)

INSERT INTO app_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO app_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2015-06-17 00:00:00.000')

INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,17.56)
INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000','2013-12-31 00:00:00.000',667.97)
INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000','2014-10-05 00:00:00.000',3.96)
INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,48.40)
INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-01-08 00:00:00.000','2013-12-31 00:00:00.000',332.03)
INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-01-08 00:00:00.000','2013-12-31 00:00:00.000',63.10)


INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-07-09 00:00:00.000',NULL,1062.29)
INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,17.56)
INSERT INTO inv_detail
VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,48.40)

select * from app_detail
select * from inv_detail
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
SELECT
 '583' AS CustID1
,'246' AS CustID2
,'2013-04-30 00:00:00.000' AS AppDate
,'1133.02' AS TotalAmount

UNION
SELECT
 '583'
,'246'
,'2015-06-17 00:00:00.000'
,'1128.25'

CustID1 CustID2 AppDate    TotalAmount
583      246    2013-04-30  1133.02
583      246    2015-06-17  1128.25
```

The first tables contains data on customers making an application on a particular date.
The second table has the invoicing details for those customers, when the invoice was send and when it was paid (cleared).
I want to know the amount of invoicing the customer had outstanding at the application date.
If the invoice was paid, then there will be a date in the ClearedDate column. If the invoice was never paid, it will be NULL.

The only way I have thought about doing it is via a loop where I just pass one AppDate at a time to the `WHERE` clause. But I was hoping I can void that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you compute the total amount? I can't follow. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowed from Blorgbeard's answer to show how this could be done without the sub-query.

```
DECLARE @app_detail TABLE (CustID1 int,CustID2 int,AppDate datetime)
DECLARE @inv_detail TABLE(CustID1 int,CustID2 int,PostDate datetime,ClearDate datetime,Amt float)

INSERT INTO @app_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @app_detail VALUES(583,246,'2015-06-17 00:00:00.000')

INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,17.56)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000','2013-12-31 00:00:00.000',667.97)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000','2014-10-05 00:00:00.000',3.96)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,48.40)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-01-08 00:00:00.000','2013-12-31 00:00:00.000',332.03)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-01-08 00:00:00.000','2013-12-31 00:00:00.000',63.10)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-07-09 00:00:00.000',NULL,1062.29)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,17.56)
INSERT INTO @inv_detail VALUES(583,246,'2013-04-05 00:00:00.000',NULL,48.40)

select a.*, sum(Amt) AS [Total]
from @app_detail a
LEFT JOIN @inv_detail i ON i.CustID1=a.CustID1
    AND i.CustID2=a.CustID2
    AND i.PostDate <= a.AppDate
    AND (i.ClearDate is null or i.ClearDate > a.AppDate)
GROUP BY a.CustID1,a.CustID2,a.AppDate
```

Comment: This looks good, and it's simpler - but OP may wish to test its performance against my answer on his real data. My test on the minimal test data indicated this was actually slower - it does a nested-loop join plus a sort, compared to `outer apply` doing only the nested-loop join.

Comment: @Blorgbeard If I were to rewrite it for myself, I'd use a union and get rid of the OR. I've always found that to be more efficient. After benchmarking and only if the OR implementation was not fast enough of course :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`outer apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) instead of a manual loop:

```
select a.*, due.Total
from app_detail a
outer apply (
    select sum(Amt) [Total]
    from inv_detail i
    where 
        i.CustID1=a.CustID1 and i.CustID2=a.CustID2 and 
        i.PostDate <= a.AppDate and (i.ClearDate is null or i.ClearDate > a.AppDate)
) due
```

It returns the correct results for me, after I removed two duplicate rows from your test data (`17.56` and `48.40` both had two entries).

This is not a particularly efficient method - it will result in a table scan (or possibly index scan, if you have an appropriate index) of `inv_detail` for every row in `app_detail`. However, I don't believe there's a way around that in this case - it's not a simple aggregate, since a row from `inv_detail` may be involved in the calculation for many rows of `app_detail`.